# Server Admin has insufficient rights to add SYSTEM DSN. Why?

Tags: windows-7, security, dsn

My Logon ID is in the Administrator Group for a server. Yet, when I run bring up the ODBC Data Source Administrator by launching it as the Administrator and navigate to the *SYSTEM* Data Source tab, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
ODBC System DSN Warning
---------------------------
You are logged on with non-Administrative privileges. System DSNs could not be created or modified
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I need to be able to create a *SYSTEM* DSN, not a User DSN. Any idea why I cannot or what I need to do to be abvle to create one?

**Update**

when I said I launched the ODBC Administrator as the Admin, I was referring to launching the following program:

```
C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe
```

However, I realized that I wanted to create a DSN for a 32 bit driver, so I then launched the following program:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

I was then able to access the System DSN tab w/o receiving an error and create the necessary DSNs.

When I then re-launched the 64-bit version (C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe) I was able to access the SYSTEM DSN tab WITHOUT seeing the "you don't have Admin rights" error that I previously saw.

...Which still confuses me why I saw it in the first place.

Sigh... I'll never understand it any better than Microsoft does.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is due to a UAC prompt that is not brought all the way through the ODBC admin app.
Try to launch C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe from a Command Prompt (Admin).

Comment: This didn't work for me - I have an elevated CMD window and opened `odbcad32.exe` and it still gave me the "You are logged on with non-Administrative privileges", weird. This is on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.

Comment: Weird - if I open `C:\Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe` (instead of `System32\odbcad32.exe`) then I don't get the message and it works fine.